# Which loss functions does h2o.gbm use by default?

Tags: loss-function, gbm, h2o

the GBM implementation of the h2o package only allows the user to specify a loss function via the  `distribution` argument, which defaults to `multinomial` for categorical response variables and `gaussian` for numerical response variables. According to the documentation, the loss functions are implied by the distributions. But I need to know which loss functions are used, and I can't find that anywhere in the documentation. I'm guessing it's the MSE for `gaussian` and cross-entropy for `multinomial` - does anybody here know if I'm right?